# Действие jQuery при нажатии на 2 класса

Tags: jquery

Работает:

```
$(document).on("click", ".class1", function(e){
  $('#id').css("display", 'none');
});
```

Возможно ли обработка 2 классов так что-то типа:

```
$(document).on("click", ".class1",".class2", function(e){
```

Или однозначно надо присваивать один класс всем блоками например:

```
<div class="one class1">1</div>
<div class="two class1">1</div>
```

Comment: `.class1, .class2`  в смысле?

Comment: @teran Действие происходит при нажатии на любой из них

Comment: именно, а надо что? не сказать что ваш вопрос понятно написан :)

Comment: это ведь обычный селектор, если действие требуется на любой то `.class1, .class2`, если дочерние то `.class1 .class2`, если два класса одновременно у элемента то `.class1.class2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне себе работает перечисление, если это необходимо:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.one,.two', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one class1">1</div>
<div class="two class1">2</div>
```

Comment: это походу не то что надо :)

Comment: @teran разберемся по ходу)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery прекрасно работает с CSS селекторами

```js
$('.one,.two').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log(this.innerHTML)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="one">1</button>
<button class="two">2</button>
```